# Variation in a parameter on an equation using Muller's method

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am using the Meller's method program which I've found in this link:

http://adorio-research.org/wordpress/?p=297

In the end of the routine it calculates the root of any fuction you input:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    def f(z):
       return z**3 +1
 xinit = 0.0
 ztol  = 1.0e-5
 ftol  = 1.0e-5
 maxiter = 100
 wantreal = False
 nroots = 3

 print zermuller(f, xinit, ztol, ftol, maxiter, wantreal, nroots)
```

However, I want to calculate for an equation like

```
 z**3 +w
```

where `w` would vary like from 1 to 2 in steps of 0.1 or something like that. So I have tried add a while command in the form:

```
w = 8
while w < 9  :
    w += 0.01 # Same as a = a + 1 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def f(z):
       return  z**3 +w
 xinit = 0.0
 ztol  = 1.0e-5
 ftol  = 1.0e-5
 maxiter = 100
 wantreal = False
 nroots = 2

 print zermuller(f, xinit, ztol, ftol, maxiter, wantreal, nroots)
```

But it doesn't do anything, only calculates for the first value of `w`, does any one know how I can make it to work, or what would be wrong in my `while` command.

Comment: `python doesn't seems to like it,` is not helping. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: There you go! "But it doesn't do anything, only calculates for the first value of w"

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
w = 8
while w < 9  :
    w += 0.01 # Same as a = a + 1
```

is just an elaborate (and approximate) alternative to

```
w = 9.01
```

You should call the function *inside* the loop

```
def f(z):
    return z**3 + w

xinit = 0.0
ztol  = 1.0e-5
ftol  = 1.0e-5
maxiter = 100
wantreal = False
nroots = 3

for i in range(11):
    w = 8.0 + i/10.0
    print zermuller(f, xinit, ztol, ftol, maxiter, wantreal, nroots)
```